# How to improve Liferay 6.2 performance?

Tags: sql-server, database, performance, liferay, jvm-arguments

I start Liferay 6.2 by running Tomcat 7.0.42 on JVM 1.7 with following options on a CentOS 64 bit server with 8G Ram , but it is still running with low speed!

```
-XX:NewSize=1024m -XX:MaxNewSize=1024m -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -Xms3072m 
-Xmx3072m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

What should I do to improve performance?

Comment: RAM is not the only performance killer - please explain what you mean with "low speed".

Comment: By low speed, I mean the long time to load pages, e.g. a page with only sign in portlet, takes about 8 seconds to completely load.

Comment: What about CPU / IO / network load during that 8 seconds?

Comment: There could be plenty of reasons for that.Could you post your server logs.Are u using LDAP for importing users,using too many portlet filters or may be using too much of un optimized scripts,css or imsages on the pages.Run some page speed analysis tool for page optimization,also is the server startup time also too much?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was solved by some DB modifications. Data fragmentation is one of the causes of reducing response time of DB. Organizing and rebuilding indexes help resolving this issue. When average of fragmentation is between 5 and 30 percent, organizing indexes (ALTER INDEX REORGANIZE) is the solution and when the average is larger than 30 percent you should rebuild the index. For more information you can refer to https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189858(v=sql.110).aspx.
Shrinking is another way that can optimize DB.

> Shrinking data files recovers space by moving pages of data from the end of the file to unoccupied space closer to the front of the file. When enough free space is created at the end of the file, data pages at the end of the file can be deallocated and returned to the file system.
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189035.aspx

Running following command allows 10% free space in DB:

```
    DBCC SHRINKDATABASE (UserDB, 10);
```

Comment: Thanks to my friends Amir & Hamed

Answer (score 0):

In Liferay Control Panel --> Server Administration, you can find some Actions which can free up memory. Like Run the garbage collector to free up memory Button, and others actions.